# Cannot get the selected value in React-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select, selectedvalue

I have a problem putting the selected value in the react select, I try to use this method `defaultValue={{ label: 8, value: 8 }}`, but it cannot work.

Below is my coding:

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("0");
  const options = [
    { value: "0", label: "0" },
    { value: "1", label: "1" },
    { value: "2", label: "2" },
    { value: "3", label: "3" },
    { value: "4", label: "4" },
    { value: "5", label: "5" },
    { value: "6", label: "6" },
    { value: "7", label: "7" },
    { value: "8", label: "8" },
    { value: "9", label: "9" },
    { value: "10", label: "10" },
    { value: "11", label: "11" },
    { value: "12", label: "12" }
  ];
  const handleTypeSelect = (e) => {
    setSelectedOption(e.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        options={options}
        onChange={handleTypeSelect}        
        value={options.filter(function (option) {
          return option.value === selectedOption;
        })}
        defaultValue={{ label: 8, value: 8 }}
        label="Single select"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Result:

[image: img1]

May I know which parts I am getting wrong? I hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Remarks: I don't want change to `const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("8");`

Code testing place: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-moon-z8x0bv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Should just be `value={selectedOption}`, and `handleTypeSelect` should be doing `setSelectedOption(e);` (`e` is `option` for `react-select`'s `onChange`).

Comment: @bryce Thanks for your answer. But I try it cannot work.

Comment: Edited my comment @Fatt Sky

Comment: @bryce Thanks for your answer. May I know how to put the variable name inside defaultValue? For example I try this cannot work defaultValue={{ label: selectedOption, value: selectedOption }}

Comment: `const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(options[8]);` (move below `options` definition) then `defaultValue={selectedOption}` @Fatt Sky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `find` instead of filter

```
 value={options.find(function (option) {
          return option.value === selectedOption;
 })}
```

The `find` method returns the **first value** that matches from the collection. Once it matches the value in findings, it will not check the remaining values in the array collection. The `filter` method returns the matched values in an **array** from the collection.

In case of value option is computed as undefined then `defaultValue` will be picked by react-select. For that try setting the state as `""`.

```
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("");
```

Full code from your sandbox:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("");
  const options = [
    { value: "0", label: "0" },
    { value: "1", label: "1" },
    { value: "2", label: "2" },
    { value: "3", label: "3" },
    { value: "4", label: "4" },
    { value: "5", label: "5" },
    { value: "6", label: "6" },
    { value: "7", label: "7" },
    { value: "8", label: "8" },
    { value: "9", label: "9" },
    { value: "10", label: "10" },
    { value: "11", label: "11" },
    { value: "12", label: "12" }
  ];
  const handleTypeSelect = (e) => {
    setSelectedOption(e.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        options={options}
        onChange={handleTypeSelect}
        value={options.find(function (option) {
          return option.value === selectedOption;
        })}
        defaultValue={{ label: "8", value: "8" }}
        label="Single select"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know how to put the variable name inside defaultValue? For example I try this cannot work defaultValue={{ label: selectedOption, value: selectedOption }}

Comment: You can define a const like `var defaultValue = { label: "8", value: "8" }` and later assigned as `defaultValue={defaultValue}`. You can also find the default value from options array using find method as options is a const array in your case.

Comment: instead of using `var` as par above comment, use `const`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works!

I just updated codesandbox :)

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-jackson-l1bbii?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know how to put the variable name inside defaultValue? For example I try this cannot work defaultValue={{ label: selectedOption, value: selectedOption }}

Answer (score 0):

remove value property in Select because React select first consider value property in which you passed in usestate initial state "0" so it always gets 0.

if you want to default value work then simply remove value in select.

```
 <Select
        options={options}
        onChange={handleTypeSelect}
       // value={options.filter(function (option) {
       // return option.value === selectedOption;
       // })}
        defaultValue={{ value: "8", label: "8" }}
        label="Single select"
      />
```

Or other option is remove defaultValue and set value which you want to default select in the useState.

```
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("8");
 <div>
      <Select
        options={options}
        onChange={handleTypeSelect}
        value={options.filter(function (option) {
          return option.value === selectedOption;
        })}
        label="Single select"
      />
 </div>
```